# How to define which kernel module to use for a device

Tags: wireless, kernel

Everything was working fine when I had just installed raring. My wireless device was using the `bcma-pci-bridge` module and my access to the Internet was flawless. Then, I decided to update my packages, as recommended by the blinking icon on the leftside bar. **Without my consent**, ubuntu switched to the `wl` kernel module, and now my wireless is not working anymore with my dual-band Cisco E4200 wireless router.

How can I go back to `bcma-pci-bridge`?

The output of `lspci -nn -d 14e4`:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1684] (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4353] (rev 01)
```

Although I believe the Ethernet card doesn't matter, does it?

EDIT:

I was trying to `modprobe bcma-pci-bridge`, but it turns out that I had to just `modprobe bcma` instead. Now I have the bcma-pci-bridge module working again.

For the record, I'm using Ubuntu Raring 64 bits with on a macbook pro 6,2 (mid 2010) with kernel `3.8.0-19-generic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can revert with this terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

We'd love to identify your device first and be certain which driver and firmware is optimal:

```
lspci -nn -d 14e4:
```

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4353] (rev 01)

Comment: I believe bcmwl-kernel-source is correct for your device; however, if bcma is working, let's not fix what isn't broken.

Comment: Hey, that's something funny. The bcmwl-kernel-source works fine with most routers. However, bcma-pci-bridge is the only one that manages to work with my E4200 cisco router. Go figure... I don't know how they compare in terms of transmission rate, power consumption, features implemented etc... But there's definitely something missing in bcmwl-kernel-source that is not being addressed simply because it's a very specific case that no one bothered fixing. I wish I had the skills to come up with a patch myself, but maybe someone else could investigate?